# How to compare column values of two tables in where clause

Tags: yii2

Here is the scenario I am trying to use

```
game_studentanswer
--> studentanswerid (primary)
--> questionid
--> answerid (this is the answer selected by user)

game_question
--> questionid

game_officialanswer
--> officalanswerid (primary)
--> questionid
--> answerid (this is the answerid for correct answer)
```

i am trying to create this query in Yii2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `game_studentanswer` LEFT JOIN `game_question` ON `game_studentanswer`.`questionid` = `game_question`.`questionid` LEFT JOIN `game_officialanswer` ON `game_question`.`questionid` = `game_officialanswer`.`questionid` WHERE (`userid`='1') AND (`game_studentanswer`.`answerid` <> `game_officialanswer`.`answerid`)
```

Here is the code

```
$query = MyGameStudentanswer::find()->joinWith('question.gameOfficialanswers')
        ->where(['userid'=>$userid])->andWhere(['answerid' => 'question.gameOfficialanswers.answerid']);
```

My problem is the "AndWhere()" part of the code - instead of comparing two columns - it assumes 'question.gameOfficialanswers.answerid' as a string value as a result the query that Yii2 performs is this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `game_studentanswer` LEFT JOIN `game_question` ON `game_studentanswer`.`questionid` = `game_question`.`questionid` LEFT JOIN `game_officialanswer` ON `game_question`.`questionid` = `game_officialanswer`.`questionid` WHERE (`userid`='1') AND (`game_studentanswer`.`answerid` = 'game_officialanswer.answerid')
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Was able to find a workaround by using ` quotes around the table and column names.

```
$query = MyGameStudentanswer::find()->joinWith('question.gameOfficialanswers')//->onCondition(['answerid' => 'question.gameOfficialanswers.answerid'])
->where(['userid'=>$userid])->andWhere('`game_studentanswer`.`answerid` = `game_officialanswer`.`answerid`');//->onCondition('questionid=game_officalanswer.questionid');
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve that before I checked! :)